# Reusing common step definitions between two feature files in cucumber (java)

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I want to know(if possible) -how to reuse step definitions related to few or all steps of a scenario from one feature file to another another?
For Example- 
in my Feature file-1 :I have below scenario/steps:

Scenario Outline: Create a new property by entering mandatory fields

```
Given As an user I Log in to application and go to property Tab
And I create a new Property from main Menu by entering details in mandatory fields- FloorName as FName, Type..etc so mant columns..
```

Step definition for create property is-

```
@And ("^I Create a new Property from main Menu by entering details in mandatory fields FloorName as ([^\"]*), Type..so on."$)
public void createNewProperty(String floorName,String propType...){
//code for all data entry part
}
```

And in my Feature file 2: I have to reuse 2nd step from above based on a condition (i.e. if there is no record exist then create new one)

Scenario Outline: Create a new space on property

```
Given As an user I Log in to application and go to Space Tab
Then I navigate to Property Details tab 
And Make sure there is at least one active listing available if not-add new
```

below is my step definition for this-

```
@And("^Make sure there is at least one active listing available if not- add new$")
    public void CheckOrCreateAnActiveListing() throws Throwable {
        //Check if active record is present else create one
        logger.info(" Verify if search has returned some matching results");
        int iRecords= leasePage.chkRowsCountOnActiveListApplet();
        if (iRecords>0) {
           logger.info(" Applet has enough active record(s) to proceed ");
        } else {
            logger.info(" Applet has no active record(s) to proceed, hence creating one ");

            //TBD *****
        }

    }
```

Here I have to reuse stuff in TBD block from Feature-1

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reuse the code. There are two solutions.

**First**, crate a common library method eg. createNewProperty and call it in both the step definitions as give below.

```
@And("^I have create a new Property from main Menu$")
public void createANewPropertyFromMainMenu(){
   //call library method createNewProperty 

}

@And("^Make sure there is at least one active listing available if not- add new$")
    public void CheckOrCreateAnActiveListing() throws Throwable {
        //Check if active record is present else create one
        logger.info(" Verify if search has returned some matching results");
        int iRecords= leasePage.chkRowsCountOnActiveListApplet();
        if (iRecords>0) {
           logger.info(" Applet has enough active record(s) to proceed ");
        } else {
            logger.info(" Applet has no active record(s) to proceed, hence creating one ");

            //call library method createNewProperty 
        }

    }
```

**Second**, you can directly call the first step definition method in second as given below, but it is not advisable.

```
@And("^Make sure there is at least one active listing available if not- add new$")
public void CheckOrCreateAnActiveListing() throws Throwable {
     //Check if active record is present else create one
     logger.info(" Verify if search has returned some matching results");
     int iRecords= leasePage.chkRowsCountOnActiveListApplet();
     if (iRecords>0) {
           logger.info(" Applet has enough active record(s) to proceed ");
     } else {
           logger.info(" Applet has no active record(s) to proceed, hence creating one ");

          //create object of step definition class and class the method
          obj.createANewPropertyFromMainMenu();
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response- Murthi, Yeah, 1st approach is best but we have to pass all required input data from Examples (cucumber table, which is for 15-20 entry fields) so we kept thest methods on pageObject classes rather than defining as standalone method in BasePage/commonLib. And when comes to 2nd approach again I'm not sure how calling this method by using stepDefinition class object will read data from related step (i.e. cucumber examples table). To make it more clear editing my question by providing stepDef for 1st scenario also. Plz suggest.

Comment: I don't think, you can call that method with data table. second approach is just calling java class method. You can pass the parameter to the method but if is hard coded or pass entire table as parameter and get the first row data and pass it to method. There is no direct way of passing it with scenario outline.